# Creating a number range from a regex-like descriptor

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a number range given a regex. This is the opposite of most questions in trying to validate if a number is in a range. I am going to be given the regex and need to create the range.

For example, given the regex "80055510[34]X" I would like to create the numbers 8005551030 through 8005551049. The "X" can be whatever, it's just what the end users are used to using (in Cisco Call Manager applications).

Given "80055512[12][12]" it would create:

8005551211
8005551212
8005551221
8005551212

Given: "800555120[0-2,9]" it would generate:

8005551200 8005551201 8005551202 8005551209

Is this possible using regular expressions or do I just need to parse things on my own and do it?

I would be coding this in Java if it makes a difference. Thanks.

Comment: You need to parse it on your own and expand appropriately. Since you want a Cartesian product expansion, I'd think about tackling it recursively.

Comment: Shouldn't you either be using `[1,2]` or `[0-29]`? Your examples are inconsistent.

Comment: @aioobe I get that, but the implication is that `[12]` means 1 *or* 2 as well. So are commas required, optional, or a typo?

Comment: The question of how to generate strings matching a given regex seems to come up quite often on Stack Overflow. Let me google this for you ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+generate

Comment: Thanks for the other pointers. I did indeed search, however I used more than just the 2 words which ended up not being all that helpful.

Based on those links and the answers here it does look like I'll have to do something myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may of course use regular expressions to *parse* the input strings<sup>*</sup>, using say `"\\[(.*?)\\]"` to find occurrences of, for instance `"[0-2,9]"`.

Other than that, I doubt that the regexp classes (Pattern, Matcher) of java will be of any help for you here. Unless you do some crazy brute-force and let the java-regexp "filter out" what numbers are valid.

---

<sup>*</sup> Provided you're not planning on supporting strange expressions like `[[4-8]-[3-9]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions should be used for pattern matching, not parsing. I guess that in your case, you would have to come up with your own mechanism to parse the regular expression.